# Is the index 2 subgroup the biggest normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

I know that any index 2 subgroup is normal.

But is it the biggest?

Answer (score 1):

I presume we're talking about finite groups here.  Since the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group, the only subgroup bigger than an index $2$ subgroup (if that exists) is the group itself.

Comment: Even if group is not finite, if group has a subgroup of index $2$, then naturally it is a maximal subgroup. (so the biggest)

Answer (score 0):

It would be appropriate to say "it is *maximal*" instead of *biggest*; this is then obvious. Then instead of $2$, a subgroup of index $p$, prime, is also maximal (=biggest in your sense), but not necessarily normal; Robert Israel's argument (2nd statement) explains why it should be maximal.

Being "maximal" and being "normal" are almost independent; in rare cases "maximal" implies "normal" (in $p$-groups for example).